# How to add margin in the border of a li tag?

Tags: css, tags, html-lists, border

I have a menu where I want the li tags have a border. I am doing this in my css :

```
.sf-menu li a
    {
       list-style-position:inside;
       border: 2px solid white;
       color:#fffefe;
    }
```

But it is a bit ugly. I want to make it work like that : [image: HERE HERE] by putting some margins. I am trying but nothing and I can't think of relevant tags in order to search on google.

Comment: could you show us your markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as well. I would like to find other solutions as well though.

```
.sf-menu li a
{
     list-style-position:inside;
     border: 2px solid white;
     border-radius: 8px;
     color:#fffefe;
     padding:8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **list-style-position** should be applied to the `<UL>` tag.
Secondly, you should set the border to the `<li>` tag, and look at your code:

```
  .sf-menu li a
```

So you are selecting `<a>` inside of `<li>` in the class `.sf-menu`, and you need to select just `<li>`, simply:

```
.sf-menu li {
   //your styles here
}
```

Please make an example on jsfiddle (or any other platform) for further help

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to set border on `li tag` not in `a tag`

```
.sf-menu li
    {
       border: 2px solid white;
    }
```

And also list-style-position should be defined in `ul tag` not in `a tag`

```
.sf-menu
    {
       list-style-position:inside;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jsFiddle. I think this is what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/nnLjK/3/

I split your `.sf-menu` and your `.sf-menu` CSS declarations a bit...